# Embedded Excel in WebBrowser (c#) - avoid separate window in elegant manner?

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am using the WebBrowser control (i.e. from System.Window.Controls) to host Excel in my C# WPF application.

Annoyingly, it will open in a new window unless I manually change the BrowserFlags key from value 0x00000008 to 0x80000A00  for a number of HKLM keys (below is a .reg files I've created to do this quickly).  With this registry change the Excel application will open inside the c# application WebBrowser control as expected.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.OpenDocumentSpreadsheet.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Sheet.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Sheet.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Template.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.TemplateMacroEnabled]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Workspace]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00
```

Note that these registry changes are undocumented in the latest Excel (there used to be an MSDN registry article to do this for earlier Excel, but there is no official word on doing this for newer Excel versions but it works).

Now annoyingly, every now and again, Excel updates will revert the registry to their default values.  Therefore a well functioning application needs to be able to set the registry value appropriately upon each launch (and put the value back to the previous setting upon closing if polite).

However, this means changing HKLM which requires UAC prompting, or giving the application admin privileges (both of which are undesirable).

Does anyone know a better way of achieving this?  The route I would guess is looking at the AxIWebBrowser2 property of the WebBrowser and doing a lower level configuration of how Excel is embedded, but this goes beyond my knowledge.  Any ideas?  Note I don't want to go down the ActiveX commercial controls approach since the WebBrowser seems very stable and is Microsoft's recommended way of embedding Excel (and hence should be more future proof).

Comment: It appears Microsoft didn't recommend embedding Office 2007 or above with `WebBrowser` because of the registry issues you have found. They recommend using an ActiveX control, though they no longer supply a sample :(

Comment: Yes you are right, the following link confirms your assertion https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304662/how-to-use-the-webbrowser-control-to-open-office-documents-in-visual-c

Comment: And the activex sample has been deleted by Microsoft but the web has some mirrors http://www.cnblogs.com/telnet_mike/archive/2011/01/17/1937785.html - does anyone know if the dsoframer sample c++ still works with latest Excel and C#?

Comment: Ok it seems this debate died in 2009 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1737c39c-9b95-4330-8235-818bfd48c76a/its-any-instead-solution-for-dsoframer?forum=winforms which means that Microsoft actually has no publicly supported means of hosting Excel in an application. I guess WebBrowser is the only sensible approach despite the above limitations unless one buys the commercial activex wrappers for a fortune or build your own one which i presume is non trivial. The fact VSTO host Excel is curious though...

Comment: [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673701/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WPF-Window-Applicati?display=Print&fid=1845984&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=26) seems like an interesting approach.

Comment: ndeed, I just launched a new question to cover all approaches a bit more fully https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49387721/what-is-the-best-way-to-embed-excel-in-c-sharp-application  I would classify this as hijacking the exe's window handle and making it a child. I am curious if there are any dangers to this. If you have views perhaps reply to the new question which provides more context and will be more easily found by others looking for this topic.