# What is the best way to embed Excel in c# application

Tags: c#, excel, webbrowser-control, activex

I want to embed MS Excel into my wpf C# application within a tabbed view, so that the user can utilise the real MS Excel (not a clone) to manipulate data generated within my application easily.

What is the most effective way to embed Excel / Office applications into your .net application going forward. Is it:

1) Webbrowser

2) ActiveX (commercial or try to fix DSOFramer from 2008)

3) Using SetParent on the window handle of Excel and making it a child window of your application.

Comment: Honestly, most applications do one of these two approaches.  Create a file checkout process, where the user has to check the file out, then check in to upload back to the original source.  Or they read the contents of the excel file in their application, allow the user to make changes within their UI then overwrite the original excel file with the new one.

Comment: Most people use third party that have already handled everything. But even there you have 2 choices : a GUI control that display excel (i.e telerik have one) or you display on your own but use a Reader/Writer library (i.e spreadsheetgear)

Comment: My use case is to have true MS Excel embedded in the application, not a GUI tool that pretends to be Excel like telerik (see 4. above).  It also does not meet the use case to simply write to Excel, the clients need the full capabilities of Excel including VBA, XLL addins etc available within the embedded Excel instance.

Comment: Unfortunately I think we have determined your customer requirements are not Microsoft supported, so they will need to change.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close - this seems pretty clearly "a specific programming problem".

Comment: NetMage provided an interesting link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673701/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WPF-Window-Applicati?display=Print&fid=1845984&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=26 in the other question I referenced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370696/embedded-excel-in-webbrowser-c-avoid-separate-window-in-elegant-manner which seems to work with Excel if you put a sleep before grabbing the window handle.  This is approach 3) above...interesting!

Comment: I don't see why this is too broad.  I am asking what is the best way to embed MS Excel into a C# application.  I have tried to be helpful by outlining the background to the problem the possible solutions I am aware of.